# How do I get this Blazor HttpGet call to work?

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, asp.net-core, blazor

I have two HttpGet calls that are identical except for the name. One works, the other doesn't. When I set breakpoints in the two calls, one is reached the other is not. GetBgQuizAnswer works, while GetBgQuizAnswerFirst fails with this error: ***'<' is an invalid start of a value.***

```
        bgQuizAnswer = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<BgQuizAnswer>("api/BgQuizAnswer/GetBgQuizAnswer");
        bgQuizAnswer = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<BgQuizAnswer>("api/BgQuizAnswer/GetBgQuizAnswerFirst");

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetBgQuizAnswerFirst")]
    public ActionResult<BgQuizAnswer> GetBgQuizAnswerFirst()
    {
        BgQuizAnswer retVal = null;
        _bgQuizAnswerService.Reset();
        if (_bgQuizAnswerService.MoveNext())
            retVal = _bgQuizAnswerService.Current;
        if (retVal != null)
        {
            return Ok(retVal); // Use Ok to indicate success and return the object
        }
        else
        {
            return NotFound(); // Optionally, return NotFound if no data is found
        }
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetBgQuizAnswer")]
    public ActionResult<BgQuizAnswer> GetBgQuizAnswer()
    {
        BgQuizAnswer retVal = null;
        _bgQuizAnswerService.Reset();
        if (_bgQuizAnswerService.MoveNext())
            retVal = _bgQuizAnswerService.Current;
        if (retVal != null)
        {
            return Ok(retVal); // Use Ok to indicate success and return the object
        }
        else
        {
            return NotFound(); // Optionally, return NotFound if no data is found
        }
    }
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you are showing us, so [by inference] there's something you are not showing us.  Change the route of the one that works and does it still work?

Comment: Renamed the first one - it still worked. Renamed the second - it switched to working. Renamed it back - returned to failing. If I knew what I wasn't showing, I'd show it.

Comment: This problem happens with JSON deserialization.  Maybe your api is returning HTML instead of JSON or something, or you're just typing the names of the methods wrongly.

Comment: Wouldn't that apply to both methods? The contents are indentical.

Comment: Document that "Renamed the second - it switched to working" a little better, inside the Question. Also add the Controller heading with attributes.

Comment: The error is almost certainly generated during deserialization.  Are you call these in the same order?   If so switch the order and what happens?  Does `_bgQuizAnswerService.Reset();` really reset.  What type of service is it?  What type of DbContext are you using?

Comment: I also think the problem is due to the api response, I mean we might get an exception in the api and it returns an html page instead of the  normal response, so it couldn't deserizalie the response. If we just want to avoid the exception, we could change the return content, for example, not `return NotFound()` but `return null` or `return "string"`. By the way, we have 2 api which are the same except the method name. I think if we changed the order of the 2 httpget lines, we could get the same result, we need to debug the methods to see why it got wrong when executing the same methods 2 times

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 probably gave you the reason of the error. I'd bet you have another page having the same route and that is returning an HTML page, especially when you tell us that changing the route name fixes it.